# Response not working for a simple python chatbot system using nltk

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, nltk, chatbot

for some reason if I type "how are you" or "how old are you" the program struggles to recognise it. I thought it was due to the tokenizer and i changed it multiple times however I'm still ending up with the same result. I would really appreciate a little help please

```
#Responses
def ai_responses():
  return [ 
    [r"hi|hello|hey", ["Hello!", "Hi there!", "Hey!"]], 
    [r"what is your name", ["My name is Chatbot.", "People call me Chatbot.", "I'm Chatbot!"]], 
    [r"how are you|how r u|how are u|hru", ["I'm doing fine, thank you.", "I'm doing great. How about you?"]], 
    [r"how old are you|how old r u|how old are u", ["As an AI, I dont have an age, however, I was created on April 27th 2023","As an AI, I dont have an age, however, I was created on Thursday 27th April 2023"]],
    [r"quit|bye|bye bye|see u|cya|see you", ["Bye! Take care.", "It was nice talking to you. See you soon!"]]
  ]

#Simple tokenizer 
def tokenize(text):
  for punc in string.punctuation:
    text = text.replace(punc, " ")
  return text.lower().split()

#---Main---
def main(): 
  clear()
  r = ai_responses() 
  print("Hi! I'm Chatbot. How can I assist you today?") 
  while True: 
    tokens = tokenize(input("You: ")) 
    for pattern, responses in r: 
      if any(token in pattern.split("|") for token in tokens): 
        print("Chatbot:", random.choice(responses))
main()
```

I've tried changing the tokenizer multiple times however it still doesn't work no matter what I do

Comment: I'd start by simplifying the code: make the responses an array of arrays instead of splitting strings in the loop. Or make it a dict with the possible user input as key and the possible answers as values. Add debug `print` statements to see what your code is doing. Good luck!